# wx.StatusBar - Why does my status bar add a gray box covering my panel?

Tags: wxpython

Why does the following code add a gray box over most of the wxPanel?

```
statusBar = wx.StatusBar(frame)
```

However, nothing like that happens for other widgets like these:

```
textbox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, size = (300,20), pos = (10,30))
button = wx.Button(panel, size = (300,20), pos = (10,60), label = "Go")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the wxStatusBar to the frame like this:

```
frame.SetStatusBar(statusBar)
```

The status bar widget requires 2 lines of code to get started while most others just take 1 line of code.